# Do not display launcher when moving desktop icons

Tags: 14.04, unity, launcher, desktop-icons

When I drag and drop Icons on the Desktop the Launcher appears (even when I'm far from the border.) This can become very annoying when I want to put a desktop icon to the left border and not in the launcher. Is there a setting to make the launcher not appear when moving around desktop icons? Using 14.04

Comment: No setting. It's happens to allow DnD on a launcher icon. Only way to prevent is modify the unity source

Answer (score 0):

The only way of doing what you want to do is to not make the launcher disappear while dragging and dropping icons right next to the launcher.

Dragging and dropping icons below the position of the launcher cannot be done in Unity, that's hard-coded behaviour.